# Searching locations in any ArcGIS Basemaps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, basemap

I am wondering if it is possible to search locations in the basemap that is used as a background map in my project or whether I can add any searchable layer (such as it happens in Google Maps?).

The problem is that I need to edit a set of points that are currently located in the wrong places. As I don’t have an extensive knowledge of the region under study, and it would be very cumbersome to first search the location in Google Maps, and then go back to ArcGIS and move the points.

Does ArcGIS have any search tool that finds the addresses/placenames of the locations I am looking for in the basemaps.

Comment: Have you looked at the Find tool?

Comment: Thank you for your tip. Which is the name of the tool? Simply, "find"?

Comment: It's called Find and you will find it on the Tools toolbar. It looks like a pair of binoculars.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap go to Customize -> Toolbars -> Geocoding

[image]

You can use the toolbar to navigate to addresses.

[image]

Comment: Yes it works. I am happy with the result.

Comment: Great. Please click check mark to indicate the correct answer.